# Endless loop after post request

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

I have a spring boot running with context `myContext` and a rest controller with method

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
@Slf4j
public class MyController {

    @SecurityRequirement(name = "OpenId")
    @PostMapping(path = "/record/import", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<String> importRecord(@RequestBody RecordJson importBody, Authentication auth, Locale locale) throws ParseException {
    ...
    }
}
```

When I make a request with postman:
`POST localhost:8080/myContext/api/v1/record/import`

the application falls into endless loop:

```
2023-04-03 14:57:39.136  INFO 22976 --- [)-192.168.0.111] o.a.c.c.C.[.[localhost].[/myContext]     : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-04-03 14:57:39.136  INFO 22976 --- [)-192.168.0.111] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-04-03 14:57:39.139  INFO 22976 --- [)-192.168.0.111] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 3 ms
2023-04-03 14:57:45.229  WARN 22976 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping for POST /myContext/
2023-04-03 14:57:45.232  INFO 22976 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.n.a.e.c.ForwardConfiguration           : No requested mapping found. Forwarding to index
2023-04-03 14:57:45.229  WARN 22976 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping for POST /myContext/
2023-04-03 14:57:45.232  INFO 22976 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.n.a.e.c.ForwardConfiguration           : No requested mapping found. Forwarding to index
2023-04-03 14:57:45.229  WARN 22976 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping for POST /myContext/
2023-04-03 14:57:45.232  INFO 22976 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.n.a.e.c.ForwardConfiguration           : No requested mapping found. Forwarding to index
... repeating of two above lines
```

until it finishes with stackoverflow ex with repeating stack entries:

```
2023-04-03 14:57:46.534  INFO 22976 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.n.a.e.c.ForwardConfiguration           : No requested mapping found. Forwarding to index
2023-04-03 14:57:46.545  WARN 22976 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping for POST /myContext/
2023-04-03 14:57:46.546  INFO 22976 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.n.a.e.c.ForwardConfiguration           : No requested mapping found. Forwarding to index
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:51491', transport: 'socket'
2023-04-03 14:58:10.378 ERROR 22976 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]      : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] threw exception

java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putVal(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1012)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.put(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1006)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.setAttribute(Request.java:1584)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.setAttribute(RequestFacade.java:540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.setAttribute(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:306)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.setAttribute(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:306)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.setAttribute(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:306)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.setAttribute(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:306)
...... repeating many lines of setAttribute 

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.setAttribute(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:306)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.setAttribute(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:306)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.setAttribute(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:306)
    at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.setAttribute(ServletRequestWrapper.java:259)
    at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.setAttribute(ServletRequestWrapper.java:259)
    at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.setAttribute(ServletRequestWrapper.java:259)
    at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.setAttribute(ServletRequestWrapper.java:259)
    at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.setAttribute(ServletRequestWrapper.java:259)
    at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.setAttribute(ServletRequestWrapper.java:259)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceUrlEncodingFilter$ResourceUrlEncodingRequestWrapper.setAttribute(ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.java:87)
    at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.setAttribute(ServletRequestWrapper.java:259)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.condition.ProducesRequestCondition.getAcceptedMediaTypes(ProducesRequestCondition.java:287)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.condition.ProducesRequestCondition.getMatchingCondition(ProducesRequestCondition.java:208)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfo.getMatchingCondition(RequestMappingInfo.java:393)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.getMatchingMapping(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:109)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.getMatchingMapping(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:67)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.addMatchingMappings(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:448)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.lookupHandlerMethod(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:408)
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.BasePathAwareHandlerMapping.lookupHandlerMethod(BasePathAwareHandlerMapping.java:103)
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping.lookupHandlerMethod(RepositoryRestHandlerMapping.java:147)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:383)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.getHandlerInternal(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.getHandlerInternal(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:67)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping.getHandler(AbstractHandlerMapping.java:498)
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.DelegatingHandlerMapping$HandlerSelectionResult.from(DelegatingHandlerMapping.java:147)
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.DelegatingHandlerMapping.getHandler(DelegatingHandlerMapping.java:114)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getHandler(DispatcherServlet.java:1261)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1043)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:711)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:385)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:313)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper$SessionCommittingRequestDispatcher.forward(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:412)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequestDispatcher.forward(HeaderWriterFilter.java:170)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:171)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:316)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1401)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1145)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1084)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:711)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:385)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:313)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper$SessionCommittingRequestDispatcher.forward(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:412)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequestDispatcher.forward(HeaderWriterFilter.java:170)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:171)
    
... repeating blocks of stacktrace
```

Other rest endpoints in that controller are working correctly. Context is set in `application.properties`.

It seems like I have two problems.

1. Spring fails to map the request correctly to my controller.
2. The no mapped method exception handling is somehow broken and redirects itself to the same url again and again.

Answer (score 1):

In Spring Boot your Context are by default not /AppName. Your Context are only /.

so try this: `POST localhost:8080/api/v1/record/import`

if you want to change your default Context you must make this steps:

1.)Insert in pom.xml the Line: `<finalName>myContext</finalName>`

for Example:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>myContext</finalName>
    </build>
```

2.) in application.properties insert this line: `server.servlet.context-path=/myContext`

3.) If you using Netbeans -> Rightklick on Project -> Properties -> Run -> Insert your Context Name in Context Path like "/myContext"

thats it, i hope this helps

Comment: thank you, I have set up the context correctly, other methods are working fine.. I will update the Q with this info

Answer (score 0):

I found out, that one of the dependencies in our project had a `@ControllerAdvice` tagged class, that handled `NoHandlerFoundException.class` with a redirect to `"/"`, which did not exist and caused the redirect handling again and an endless loop..

If anybody has similar issue, look for `NoHandlerFoundException.class` handling.